# \noalign in a \list environment

Tags: lists, align

I am using a list environment to set some text and equations. The equations are displayed using flalign (but all that follows is also true for align), and they line up correctly with the text that precedes and follows them. But if I want to introduce a line between two lines of equations, using `\noalign`, then the inserted text is flushed completely left, and the leftmargin is ignored:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{(a)}{%
  \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)}%
  \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep%
  \partopsep=0pt%
  }
\item Some text to make a line for the first example, using
  \texttt{\textbackslash align}.
  \begin{flalign*}
    &x^2+y^2=a^2&&\\
    \noalign{\text{a comment}} &r^2=a^2&&
  \end{flalign*}
  And some text to close the whole thing.
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

This yields:
[image]

I know that I can fix this, for example by defining a command like `\leftalign`, which would precede the text with an appropriate `\hspace`, but I wondered if anyone could explain to me why `\noalign` ignores the leftmargin setting. I feel sure I'm missing something that might be important, but I haven't found an explanation anywhere.

Comment: can't explain technically why `\noalign` doesn't work, but `\shortintertext` (requires `mathtools`) *will* do what you want.

Comment: The explanation you have asked for is pretty long; moreover, its level of detail depends on your level of expertize with (La)TeX.  For example, do you know what `\parshape` is?  However, from a general point of view, you can’t expect a primitive command like `\noalign` to cope correctly with LaTeX constructs: it’s always best to avoid the use of such primitives altogether.  Finally, note that `\text` inside `\noalign` is superfluous (you are no longer in a mathematical context inside a `\noalign`).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to barbara's suggestion, here I use an `\rlap` of the text, with some vertical space added too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{list}{(a)}{%
  \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)}%
  \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep%
  \partopsep=0pt%
  }
\item Some text to make a line for the first example, using
  \texttt{\textbackslash align}.
  \begin{flalign*}
    &x^2+y^2=a^2&&\\[3pt]
    &\text{a comment}\\[3pt]
    &r^2=a^2&&
  \end{flalign*}
  And some text to close the whole thing.
\end{list}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\text` inside `\rlap` serves no purpose.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thank you for the reminder...fixed.

Comment: Well, I would have rather dropped the `\rlap`, and retained the `\text`—or, more precisely, `&\text{...}`… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti My brain was definitely in neutral gear yesterday! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do with `\shortintertext` (requires `mathtools`) or `\intertext` (just `amsmath`). You can also exploit `enumitem` instead of doing all computations by hand for your `list`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*,partopsep=0pt]
\item Some text to make a line for the first example, using
  \texttt{align}.
  \begin{flalign*}
  &x^2+y^2=a^2&&\\
  \shortintertext{a comment}
  &r^2=a^2&&
  \end{flalign*}
  And some text to close the whole thing.

\item Something else
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` package is loaded just to show the bounding box of the text area.

[image]

You need to be aware, though, that different document classes may have *very different* ideas about the whole thing. If you change `article` into `amsart`, you'd get

[image]

You can do with `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*,partopsep=0pt]
\begin{fleqn}
\item Some text to make a line for the first example, using
  \texttt{align}.
  \begin{align*}
  &x^2+y^2=a^2 \\
  \shortintertext{a comment}
  &r^2=a^2
  \end{align*}
  And some text to close the whole thing.

\item Some text to make a line for the first example, using
  \texttt{align}.
  \begin{equation*}
  x^2+y^2=a^2
  \end{equation*}
  a comment
  \begin{equation*}
  r^2=a^2
  \end{equation*}
  And some text to close the whole thing.
\end{fleqn}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `amsart` you should only change `\begin{fleqn}` into `\begin{fleqn}[\leftmargin]` to get

[image]

Adding a setting to `itemsep` would be better.